# Db2 joining sysibm.systables to sysibm.syscolumns

Tags: join, db2

when joining sysibm.systables to sysibm.syscolumns what are the best keys to use? accessesing db2 through sql server 2014 openquery

```
select a.name table_name, b.name column_name
from openquery(dw,'
select *
from sysibm.systables a
inner join sysibm.syscolumns b on ...
with ur');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is table name and column name, you don't need to even join to systables.

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name 
from syscolumns
```

If you really need to join, then `table_schema`, `table_name` would be the appropriate keys...

Note that I wouldn't use `openquery(dw,'select * ...')`, no sense in pulling back columns you aren't interested in.

This would be ok, `select * from openquery(dw,'select table_name, column_name ...')`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on DB2 platform you use.

[DB2 for Z/OS catalog tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_catalogtablesintro.html)
[Db2 for i catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm)
[Db2 for LUW Catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html)

```
-- Db2 for LUW & DB2 for Z/OS
SELECT *
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES T
JOIN SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS C ON C.TBCREATOR = T.CREATOR AND C.TBNAME = T.NAME;

-- Db2 for LUW
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T
JOIN SYSCAT.COLUMNS C ON C.TABSCHEMA = T.TABSCHEMA AND C.TABNAME = T.TABNAME;

-- Db2 for IBM i
SELECT *
FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES T
JOIN QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS C ON C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME;
```

Note about Db2 for LUW.
`SYSIBM` tables are not documented, but you may use the 1-st query above as well.
It's advisable to use `SYSCAT` views built on top of these `SYSIBM` tables instead.